# A more concise proof for $(x+y+z)^3>27(-x+y+z)(x-y+z)(x+y-z)$

Tags: inequality

> The question is to prove
> $$
> (x+y+z)^3>27(-x+y+z)(x-y+z)(x+y-z), 
> $$
> for $x\neq y \neq z,\ x,y,z>0$.

My proof below:
$$
27(-x+y+z)(x-y+z)(x+y-z)=-27(x^3+y^3+z^3+2xyz)+27\left\{x^2(y+z)+y^2(z+x)+z^2(x+y)\right\}
$$

Adding and subtracting $(x+y+z)^3$ to this, we get the RHS as
$$
(x+y+z)^3-28(x^3+y^3+z^3)-60xyz+24\left\{x^2(y+z)+y^2(z+x)+z^2(x+y)\right\}
\label{eq1}
\tag{1}
$$

It can easily be proved that
$$
2(x^3+y^3+z^3)>x^2(y+z)+y^2(z+x)+z^2(x+y)>6xyz
$$

This can be converted into equalities as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&2(x^3+y^3+z^3)=x^2(y+z)+y^2(z+x)+z^2(x+y)+q_1 \\
&2(x^3+y^3+z^3)=6xyz+q_2 \\
&\{q_1,q_2|\text{ }q_2>q_1>0\}
\end{aligned}
$$

Using these results in $\eqref{eq1}$, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
27(-x+y+z)(x-y+z)(x+y-z)&=(x+y+z)^3-28(x^3+y^3+z^3)-20(x^3+y^3+z^3)-10q_2+48(x^3+y^3+z^3)-24q_1\\
&=(x+y+z)^3-10q_2-24q_1
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore, we can say
$$
(x+y+z)^3>27(-x+y+z)(x-y+z)(x+y-z)
$$

**My question is: Is there a simpler way to do this?**

Comment: @Abhishek A Udupa are $x,y,z$ positive reals ?

Comment: dear Abhishek, you may wish to clarify what restrictions you have on $x,y,z$. for instance, if $x=y=z$ then the strict inequality does not hold, and if $x=y=0$ and $z=-1$ then not even the natural weakened inequality holds

Comment: You wrote "It can easily be proved $2(x^3+y^3+z^3)>x^2(y+z)+y^2(z+x)+z^2(x+y)>6xyz$" which can easily be proved false if $x=y=z>0$.

Comment: Not to mention if the statement is true for $x = a; y=b; z=c$ the the statement will be false for $x = -a; y=-b; z=-c$.  Restrictions of some sort must be applied.

Comment: Also if $x = y = z$ then $(x+y+z)^3 = (3x)^3 = 27x^3=27(-x+x+x)^3 = 27(-x+y+z)(x-y+z)(x+y-z)$.

Comment: I'm sorry that I did not include the constraints on the values of $x$,$y$ and $z$. I've added 'em now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\ \ \ p = -x+y+z$; $\ \ \ q= x-y+z$; $\ \ \ r = x+y-z$.

Notice that $p+q+r = x+y+z$

In case, $p,q,r>0$.

So, by AM-GM

$$\cfrac{p+q+r}{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{pqr}$$

$$\cfrac{x+y+z}{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{(-x+y+z)(x-y+z)(x+y-z)}$$

On cubing,

$$\cfrac{(x+y+z)^3}{27} \ge (-x+y+z)(x-y+z)(x+y-z)  $$

Therefore:

$$\boxed{(x+y+z)^3 \ge 27(-x+y+z)(x-y+z)(x+y-z)}$$

Equality holds for $x=y=z$, but since that doesn't match what the question requires, you can ignore the equality sign.

---

As fleablood has suggested, **note that**:

If $x,y,z$ are positive then at most one of the $p,q,r$ is non-positive (as only one of $x,y,z$ can be larger than the sum of the other two) and if that were the case we'd have the simple case that $pqr≤0$ but $(x+y+z)^3>0$.

Comment: dear Crease, +1, but it is not quite sufficient to have $x,y,z>0$, since that alone does not guarantee $p,q,r\geqslant 0$ (for instance, take $x=3$ and $y=z=1$), and you need that latter condition in order to apply AM-GM

Comment: If any of $x,y,z$ are allowed to be negative (or zero) then for any $x,y,z$ triplet we'd need to allow the $-x,-y,-z$ triplet and that would flip the less than sign.  So it is reasonable to presume the OP assumed $x,y,z$ are all positive.  But I don't think presuming that $p,q,r$ are all positive (or in other words that each term is less than the sum of the other two) is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: I think you should include a note that if $x,y,z$ are positive then  at most one of the $p,q,r$ is non-positive (as only one of $x,y,z$ can be larger than the sum of the other two) and if that were the case we'd have the simple case that $pqr \le 0$ but $(x+y+z)^3 > 0$.

Comment: Why did you remove the equality sign in the boxed inequality? Equality could hold, like when $ x = y = z$.